# Term D is decreasing as the term t is increasing, but the plot isn't picking up any of the points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've made the term D decrease by a certain value each time no problem but for some reason the plot isn't plotting any of the points and I'm not sure why, any help that can be provided would be much appreciated. The code I'm using is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

dam=0.82

"computation"
D=dam
Dcrit=2.6*10**-10
C2=0.07
t=0
while t<10:
        t
        print(t)
        D
        print(D)
        deltaD=D-Dcrit
        print (deltaD, 'damage')
        Sdam=deltaD
        print (Sdam, 'stimulus')
        dD=C2*Sdam
        print(dD,'change in damage')
        D=D-dD
        print (D, 'Damage')
        t+=1
        print (t, 'time')

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Damage vs time')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Damage')
plt.plot(t,D,'r-')
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of statements that make no sense (like `t`, `D`, `"computation"`, etc.) But the problem is elsewhere: `plt.plot` requires two lists: a list of x's and a list of y's. Instead, you pass two scalar variables, `t` and `D`. You shall collect the calculated values of `t` and `D` into two lists and then plot them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the end of your while loop, `t` and `D` are each scalar values, so when you call `plt.plot`, you're only plotting a single point. You need to add your updated values of t and D to a pair of lists, and then call `plt.plot` with those lists as your arguments.

A simple way you can create a list with new values as they are calculated is by starting with an empty list, `[]`, then using the list's [append](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append) method. Check out the documentation for how to use it.

I'm also not sure why you have lines that are just `"computation"`, `t`, and `D`. Those lines aren't doing anything. It looks like what you want to do there is to leave a comment. A `#` followed by text indicates a comment, which is not executable code. So, for instance, instead of writing

```
"computation"
```

You'll want to write

```
# Computation
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, but how do i make the pair of lists? the lines "computation", t and d are just there to help me visualise what's going on better, still quite new to coding.

Comment: @Rogun01 I've updated my answer with a little more detail, but if you're unfamiliar with lists, I recommend just reading up on lists, tuples, sets, and dictionaries before trying to do anything else. They're basic Python data structures that are pretty crucial to understand how to use.

Comment: That's me got it all working thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Rogun01 Glad you figured it out!